# What's a good way to store a lot of small texts with metadata with reactNative?

Tags: android, ios, react-native, jsx

I am developing an app that will displays a series of small texts everyday and I have been wondering what's the best way to store them. I intend to change them only when I update it to new versions so.

Comment: You mean, you need to update those small texts only when you update your APP to a new version?

Comment: Yes, exactly that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you need to update those small texts only when you update your APP to a new version, I think the best way is to store them in a local storage such as `AsyncStorage`.

`AsyncStorage` is an unencrypted, asynchronous, persistent, key-value storage system that is global to the app.

You can refer the docs of `AsyncStorage` [here](https://reactnative.dev/docs/asyncstorage)